# React - iterating through an array and Events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Suppose I have an array of cars that I use to set an inital state:

```
const [ carState, setCarstate ] = useState({
    cars: [
      {model: 'Ferarri', yearOfFabrication: 2001},
      {model: 'Toyota', yearOfFabrication: 2005},
      {model: 'Tesla', yearOfFabrication: 2017},
      {model: 'Ford Mustang', yearOfFabrication: 2003}
    ]
});
```

Can someone please explain why the below code is not showing any cars?

```
{carState.cars.map(car => {<Car model={car.model} age={car.yearOfFabrication}/>})}
```

and this one it's working?

```
{carState.cars.map(car => <Car model={car.model} age={car.yearOfFabrication}/>)}
```

The only difference between those two piece of code is, that the first encapsulates the return in a block of code. So perhaps this is not a React question but rather an ES6 arrow functions question?

Also, consider the below component which is passing a method reference through props:

```
<Input handler={() => changeCarNameHandler}/>
```

This doesn't work as expected, as it should call the changeCarNameHandler method upon a change event, here's the component code:

```
const input = props => {
    return(
        <input onChange={props.handler}></input>
    )
}
```

However, this is working

```
<Input handler={(event) => changeCarNameHandler(event)}/>
```

Can someone please clarify this? If you can also provide some resources where I can read more about this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: The `.map(car => { <Car /> })` one is missing the `return` statement so returning `undefined`. Meanwhile the `.map(car => <Car />)` actually returning with **JSX**.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
{carState.cars.map(car => {<Car model={car.model} age={car.yearOfFabrication}/>})}
```

If you're adding curly braces after arrow ( => ) then you have to explicitly add a return statement for rendering your **Car** component 
so it looks-

```
{carState.cars.map(car => { return (<Car model={car.model} age={car.yearOfFabrication}/>)}
)}
```

and

```
{carState.cars.map(car => <Car model={car.model} age={car.yearOfFabrication}/>)}
```

Above code works without return because it doesn't have curly braces after arrow( => ) so a single line code without a curly brace implicitly refers to a return statement in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Naturally functions without a return statement return undefined by default.

This changes with arrow functions, which can potentially have an implicit return.

In the case that your arrow function has a single expression as the function body, that expression will be executed, and the resulting value will be implicitly returned when the function is called.

```js
const simple = () => 'code'
simple()    // returns 'code'
```

For an arrow function to have an implicit return, an expression is required. But sometimes we need to use statements (if-else etc).

> In a programming language, an expression returns or is replaceable with a value. A statement will execute some code without a resulting value.

For arrow functions to contain statements the function body must be surrounded by {curlies}. And as soon as you have curly braces surrounding your function body, returns are no longer implicit -- for either statements or expressions.

```js
const simple = () => { return 'code' }
simple()     // returns 'code'

const broken = () => { 'code' }
broken()       // returns undefined
```